# Generic method/class custom implementation for specified type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, .net-core

Is there any way to make this code compile or some other alternative.
This implementation is only a example.

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    using System;

    public static class Temp<T>
        where T : struct
    {
        public static T DoSomething()
            => throw new NotImplementedException(); // common implementation

        public static int DoSomething()
            => 10; // custom implementation for specified type
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean `default(T)`? what's the error message you get while compiling?

Comment: @Rahul implementation is only example. it could be something else

Comment: @Rahul Type 'Temp<T>' already defines a member called 'GetDefault' with the same parameter types

Comment: you are passing generic parameter already so you can pass it int when calling why you need method separately ?

Comment: The question is unclear because by throwing an exception for the "common" implementation you're not showing why you need a common implementation. That method doesn't do anything so why not just delete it? If you want a static method that does something with an `int` then just write one. If you want a method that does something with a different type, write that method. So what is the problem?

Comment: @ScottHannen I just wanna know if there's any way to explicitly override generic method

Comment: No but you could extend the implementation to check for a type and do some action (although it would not be considered good design).

Comment: No, that's not overriding. In c#, methods must differ by parameters and/or name

Comment: The problem is that i use this Temp class in other generic class and wanted not to use reflection for calling for example `GetDefault{Type}` method

Comment: Does your class need to be `static`? You can't override static methods.

Comment: In .NET method overloads are ambiguous when they don't define different arguments. Think about this; how would the runtime know which one to call (perhaps, I choose not to assign the result)? Also, static classes actually don't subscribe to all principles of OOP, so overriding methods or implicit interface implementations aren't really applicable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 alternatives.

```
|               Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev | Allocated |
|--------------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|----------:|
|     Benchmark_Single | 306.8 ns | 2.867 ns | 2.682 ns |       0 B |
| Benchmark_Reflection | 581.8 ns | 3.062 ns | 2.864 ns |       0 B |
```

-

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    using System.Reflection;

    public static class TempSingle<T>
        where T : struct
    {
        public static T DoCustom()
        {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
            {
                return (T)((object)int.MinValue);
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(ushort))
            {
                return (T)((object)ushort.MinValue);
            }

            return default;
        }
    }

    public static class TempReflection<T>
        where T : struct
    {
        public readonly static Func<T> Factory = GetFactory();

        private static int GetDefaultInt32()
        {
            return int.MinValue;
        }

        private static ushort GetDefaultUInt16()
        {
            return ushort.MinValue;
        }

        private static Func<T> GetFactory()
        {
            Type type = typeof(T);

            MethodInfo method = typeof(TempReflection<T>)
                .GetMethod($"GetDefault{type.Name}", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            return Expression
                .Lambda<Func<T>>(Expression.Call(method))
                .Compile();
        }

        public static T DoCustom()
        {
            return default;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From reading the comments - if the intent is to override methods then the methods can't be static. The sample code where the "common" implementation throws a `NotImplementedException` suggests that you don't want there to be a base implementation, only overridden implementations. In that case you could do this:

```
public abstract class Temp<T>
    where T : struct
{
    public abstract T GetDefault();
}
```

Because it's `abstract` you can't create an instance of it. You have to create inherited classes.

```
public class IntTemp : Temp<int>
{
    public override int GetDefault()
    {
        // whatever your implmementation is
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess this is a alternative but sill would need reflection to call it in other generic class. Other is making a single implementation for the generic method and checking for `typeof(T) == typeof(int)` but i dont think the compiler would optimize it. It could be slow if it had to check for each type maybe.

Comment: I'm not following that at all. More often than not if you need runtime type checking or reflection something has gone wrong. Not always, usually. If there are more details about how this is used then they should be in the question.